# On Windows 7, need to copy files from A\ to B\ that are not present in B\

Tags: shell, directory, file-copying

I need to copy files of a certain type (*.vcproj) from a folder tree A\ to the corresponding folder in tree B.  There would be several levels of nested folders under A\ and the same folder structure exists within B\, though some folders from A\ *may* not exist in B\ and vice versa.

I have access to cygwin, perl and powershell.  Just not sure how to go about this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) should do what you need. `robocopy ./a ./b *.vcproj /s` will turn this:

```
/a
  /dir
    test.vcproj
  another.vcproj

/b
  /otherDir
```

Into this:

```
/a
  /dir
    test.vcproj
  another.vcproj

/b
  /dir
    test.vcproj
  /otherDir
  another.vcproj
```

Comment: That worked - thank you!  Had no idea that util even existed!  Now I just have to figure out how to get ClearCase to recognize the new files I've copied (robocopy said I copied nearly 2300!!!)